# Can't connect PHP to my Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, installation, path, php-ini

I got stuck while setting up PHP on my Mac. I downloaded it via brew and I have it on my computer.

```
PHP 8.0.26 (cli) (built: Nov 23 2022 05:33:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.26, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.26, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

this is what i get when I type `php --ini` in Terminal:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0
  Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/php.ini
  Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d
  Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```

I tried to add `/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0` into my `settings.json` but it didn't work out.
I appreciate any help!

I tried to change path of PHP to MAMP's PHP, but it did not apply. Also I have `phpinfo.php` file that is located in:
`/Library/WebServer/Documents/phpinfo.php`

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: When I type my code in Visual studio and click run , it returns this in output below: [Running] php "/Users/lizolda/Desktop/php/payment.php"
/bin/sh: php: command not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.009 seconds
and when I try to change the path to php to execute it it returns or this:
spawn /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpinfo.php EACCES
or that it can not valid php executable.